# Velleman 3.7.1 - Uniqueness Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Context and level: Freshman undergraduate just out of calculus 1 doing intro to proofs course

Questions:

- Is my proof correct?
- Is it too verbose, too terse or just right?
- Any other feedback about style or anything?

Theorem. Suppose $F$ is a family of sets. Prove that there is a unique set $A$ that has the following two properties:

(a) $F \subseteq P(A)$

(b) $\forall B(F \subseteq P(B) \rightarrow A \subseteq B)$

Proof. Let $A = \cup F$. Suppose $C \in F$. Then clearly, $C \subseteq \cup F$. It follows that $C \in P(\cup F)$.  Since $C$ was an arbitrary set in $F$, we get $F \subseteq P( \cup F)$. Now suppose $F \subseteq P(B)$. Since $C \in F$, it follows that $C \in P(B)$ or in other words $C \subseteq B$. Since $C$ was an arbitrary set in $F$, it follows that $\cup F \subseteq B$.

To see that $A=\cup F$ is a unique solution, Let $Y$ be an arbitrary set such that $F \subseteq P(Y)$ and $\forall B(F \subseteq P(B) \rightarrow Y \subseteq B)$. Applying the second assumption to $\cup F$ gives $Y \subseteq \cup F$. And since $\forall B(F \subseteq P(B) \rightarrow \cup F \subseteq B)$, we get $\cup F \subseteq Y$. Hence $Y = \cup F$. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small quibble: In the first paragraph, I would say that the sentence "Since $C$ was an arbitrary set in $F$, we get $F \subseteq P(\cup F)$" signals to the reader that you are done with the arbitrary set $C$.  So I don't think you should refer to $C$ again two sentences later.  After the sentence "Now suppose $F \subseteq P(B)$," your goal is to prove $\cup F \subseteq B$.  So I would then say "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\cup F$.  Then we can choose some set $C \in F$ such that $x \in C$."  Now you can continue to prove $C \subseteq B$ as you did, and then conclude that since $x \in C$, it follows that $x \in B$.

In the second paragraph, when you say "Applying the second assumption to $\cup F$," you are using the fact that $F \subseteq P(\cup F)$.  You might want to mention how you know that that is true.